# Sporadic simple groups in GAP

Tags: gap

I sincerely apologize in advance for this simple question.

I recently started learning GAP and I am having difficulties finding Sporadic simple groups in GAP. For example, if I want to find the order of the symmetric group $S_{10}$, I know that **Order(SymmetricGroup(10))** works. I also know how to call certain sporadic simple groups, to be precise, Mathieu groups. eg:-**Order(MathieuGroup(12))**

Could anyone please tell me how to find the remaining Sporadic groups.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a command `SimpleGroup` that takes a name. e.g.
`SimpleGroup(“HS”);`
Note that Monster and Baby Monster are not available yet, and some of the larger groups require the `atlasrep` package.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! This really helped me! @ahulpke